# I can't open my WordPress website because of some DNS issue

Tags: wordpress, dns, provider, domain-name, bluehost

When I go to my website URL trutpress.co It loads for about 1 minute and then I get the following message:

[image: WordPress link error]

I got my domain from Bluehost, and It worked perfectly, but know I am facing this error and I don't get what is the problem:
[image][image]

And when I try to login into my wp-admin from Bluehost I also get the same message after 1 minute of loading...
[image]

Here are my DNS configurations:

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

I have no idea what the issue is, can someone help with this?

Comment: Works from here. Notice that your domain name is misspelled near the top of your question.